# checkUnique function?

Tags: php, function, mysqli

Hey, so I have created a function to check the DB for unique entries, but when I call the function it doesn't seem to work and gives me a fatal error any ideas from the function or do you wish to see the sign up page calling it. Thanks :)

```
 //Check for unique entries
    function checkUnique($table, $field, $compared)
    {
        $query = $mysqli->query('SELECT  '.$mysqli->real_escape_string($field).' FROM '.$mysqli->real_escape_string($table).' WHERE "'.$mysqli->real_escape_string($field).'" = "'.$mysqli->real_escape_string($compared).'"');
        if(!$query){ 
            return TRUE; 
        }   
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

The page calling it.....

```
if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password']==$_POST['password_confirm'] && !empty($_POST['email']) && validateEmail($_POST['email']) == TRUE && checkUnqiue('users', 'email', $_POST['email']) == TRUE && checkUnique('users', 'username', $_POST['username']) == TRUE)
```

Erorr....

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function checkunqiue() in /home/mbattles/public_html/home/signup.php on line 17
```

Comment: The errors it gives would help

Comment: When getting fatal errors, please always include the exact error message and line where it happens.

Answer (score 3):

`checkUnqiue` is not `checkUnique`

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that the double quotes you are using are not causing the problems?

For example, the bit that says:

```
' WHERE "'.$mysqli->real_escape_string($field).'" = "'
```

Changing it to:

```
' WHERE '.$mysqli->real_escape_string($field).' = "'
```

work for you?

( or what Arkh just posted ;)

Answer (score 0):

> "undefined function checkunqiue()"

Check your spelling of the function name